# Xcode map showing area of location, but not point of location

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, coordinates

I am trying to get my app to display differnt locations on a map. When I hit  the location button it will zoom into the area on the map, but doesn't mark the spot, with a blue dot or pin.

this is what I have.

```
-(IBAction)loc
{ 
  MKCoordinateRegion region= {{0.0,0.0},{0.0,0.0}};
  region.center.latitude=34.245832;
  region.center.longitude=-88.722346;
  region.span.longitudeDelta=0.01f;
  region.span.latitudeDelta=0.01f;
  [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation for [MKMapView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview) (particularly the section on **Annotating the Map**), and [MKMapViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate)

Basically, you'll need to…

1. Define an object that conforms to `MKAnnotation`
2. Create an instance of that object and set its `coordinate`
3. `addAnnotation` to the map view
4. Call `showAnnotations` to zoom the map to the desired annotations
5. To display a custom pin, implement `MKMapViewDelegate` method `mapView(_:viewFor:)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mark the location, you'll need to add an annotation or an overlay.

See [MKPointAnnotation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkpointannotation?language=objc) and [MKPinAnnotationView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkpinannotationview?language=objc).